# Fluent nhibernate duplicate registers with one-to-many mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

When i save a entity that has a one-to-many (HasMany) relationship, on database the registers are duplicated.

Picture of PedidoVenda Table:

[image]

Picture of ItemPedidoVenda Table:

[image]

I can see in this pictures that the problem is because the id of ItemPedidoVenda is one forward that PedidoVenda id. But this is saved automatically. What can be this ?

My properties in the classes are these:

```
public class PedidoVenda {

    public virtual IList<ItemPedidoVenda> Itens { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ItemPedidoVenda {

    public virtual PedidoVenda Pedido { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The mappers:

PedidoVendaMapper:

```
    HasMany(x => x.Itens)
        .KeyColumn("PEDIDO_ID")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All();
```

ItemPedidoVendaMapper:

```
References(x => x.Pedido)
            .Column("PEDIDO_ID").Cascade.All();
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding an ItemPedidoVenda instance to the list of items in PedidoVenda, you must make sure that you set the Pedido property in ItemPedidoVenda to the correct instance.

I'm pretty sure you're not doing that.

What I mostly do, is prevent that the user of my API (the programmer :) ) cannot add items to the list directly.  Instead, I write an Addxxx method which adds items to the list.

Next to that, you must make sure that you use the correct collection-type.  i'd suggest a set in your case

Like this:

```
public class PedidoVenda {

    private ISet<ItemPedidoVenda> _itens = new HashedSet<ItemPedidoVenda>();

    // The public property which returns the collection is a REadOnlyCollection so the user cannot mess around with it.
    public ReadOnlyCollection<ItemPedidoVenda> Itens 
    { 
        get 
        {
           return new List<ItemPedidoVenda>(_itens).AsReadOnly();
        } 
    }

    public void AddPedido( ItemPedidoVenda item )
    {
       if( _itens.Contains(item) == false )
       {
           item.Pedido = this; // Here, make sure that the reference is filled out.
           _itens.Add(item);
       }
    }
```

}